# What are all the objects that can go in a Snowflake schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a program that requires a full and complete list of all the objects that can possibly go inside a schema in snowflake, but I can not find such a list in the documentation.

Comment: I don't need the objects in a particular schema, I need a list of all object types that could possibly go into any schema

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the CREATE statement, it has a list of all account and database object types: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create.html

Comment: I believe that answeres my question, if you add it as an answer then I can accept it

Comment: [Objects hierarchy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/_images/securable-objects-hierarchy.png) and [Access Control Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the CREATE statement, it has a list of all account and database object types: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create.html